# Youtube Video Not Playing In iOS Using YTPlayerView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, youtube

- My selected Youtube Video Not Playing In UIWebView as well as YTPlayerView

Using YTPlayerView Code is below

```
    NSDictionary *playerVars = @{
                                     @"playsinline" : @1,
                                     @"autoplay" : @1,
                                     @"controls" : @1
                                     };
        NSString *VideoID = [self extractYoutubeIdFromLink:self.videoLink];
        [self.playerView loadWithVideoId:@"rT55rmXXLrg" playerVars:playerVars];
//    [self.playerView loadWithVideoId:@"rT55rmXXLrg"];
```

- Full Video URL: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rT55rmXXLrg&app=desktop#fauxfullscreen
- If i am try to play using `UIWebView` than also same issue getting.

[image]

Comment: Are you use podfile  for YTPlayerView

Comment: Did you add Assets directory for `YTPlayerView`?

Comment: No, i added file manual with Assets

Comment: Also, i checked Last HTML String take From YTPlayerView And So It's Working Fine In Browser.

Comment: If you use UIWebView you can attach Safari Web Inspector to your app in Develop menu. Then you can see the JavaScript console, and see if there are errors.